# No explicit implementation for

Tags: haskell

Estoy intentando hacer El problema de las jarras en Haskell  tengo mi clase principal.

```
module Jarras where
import Grafo_busq_prof
import Data.List ((\\), nub)
data PJarras = PJ Int Int deriving (Show,Eq)
data Jarras = J Int Int deriving (Show,Eq)
data Expr = Núm Integer
          | Op Ops Expr Expr
          deriving (Eq)
data Ops = Sum | Res | Pro | Div
          deriving ( Eq, Show )
ops :: PJarras -> [Jarras -> Jarras]
ops (PJ mx my) =
     [llX, llY, vaX, vaY, voXY, voYX]
     where llX (J _ y) = J mx y
           llY (J x _) = J x my
           vaX (J _ y) = J 0 y
           vaY (J x _) = J x 0
           voXY (J x y) = if s <= my then J 0 (s) else J (s-my) my
                          where s=x+y
           voYX (J x y) = if s <= mx then J (s) 0 else J mx (s-mx)
                          where s=x+y
instance Grafo Jarras where
     suc c = nub [f c | f <- ops (PJ 4 3)] \\ [c]
jarras :: Int -> [[Jarras]]
jarras z =
     caminosDesde (J 0 0) test []
     where test (J x y) = x==z || y==z
másCorta :: [[a]] -> [a]
másCorta = foldr1 (\ x y -> if length x < length y then x else y)
```

Y la clase que estoy importando.

```
module Grafo_busq_prof where
class Eq v => Grafo v where
     vértices :: [v]
     suc      :: v -> [v]
     camino   :: v -> v -> [v]
     caminosDesde :: v -> (v -> Bool) -> [v] -> [[v]]
     tv       :: v -> [v] -> Bool
     -- Métodos por defecto:
     camino u v = head (caminosDesde u (== v) [])
     caminosDesde o te vis
         | te o      = [o:vis]
         | otherwise = concat [caminosDesde o' te (o:vis) |
                               o' <- suc o,
                               tv o' vis]
     tv = notElem
```

Soy nuevo utilizando es te lenguaje y al momento de ejecutarse me suelta el siguiente error se supone que vértices no tiene implementación y que lo declare en la instancia Grafo Jarras pero no entiendo el como según yo no se necesita.

```
 Jarras.hs:22:10: warning: [-Wmissing-methods]
        • No explicit implementation for
            ‘vértices’
        • In the instance declaration for ‘Grafo Jarras’
       |
    22 | instance Grafo Jarras where    |
```

Me podrían dar una solución por favor.

Comment: Creo que el error es bastante explícito: en la instancia `Grafo Jarras` sólo has definido el método `suc`. Si dejas la definición por defecto de los demás, aún te faltaría definir `vértices`.

Comment: Creo que estás confundiendo una clase de programación orientada a objetos con una clase en haskell. No es lo mismo. Un clase en haskell es lo que se denomina "type class", que es el aproximadamente-equivalente en Java a una Interface, y en `python` a una `abc` o un `protocol`